# Database open in Visual Studio and SSMS at same time

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, visual-studio, ssms

I can only have my database open in Visual Studio OR SSMS, but not at the same time. It is just the default DB that comes along with a new ASP.NET MVC solution (localhost connection). I attached the .mdf in sql server management studio and can see all the tables and query the DB just fine, but if that connection is open, I cannot run my web application simultaneously because I get an error about it being used by another process.

Is there any work around for this? It is very inconvenient to have to close out of VS and round-robin each time I need to query the DB in ssms.

Comment: This sounds rather odd what if you open 2 instances of Visual Studio and launch the web app simultaneously ... can you then access the Database..? sounds like you have something exclusively locking the db table(s)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check whether your default DB is configured to allow multiple user access in the same time. In *Management Studio*, open database properties window. In *Options* page, check *State* -> *Restrict Access* field. It should be set to *MULTI_USER*, not *SINGLE_USER*.